# Creating a DTO model and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create following output in ASP web API:

```
User[] 
--> Category[]
     --> Transaction[]
```

So I have many user with several categories and a lot of transaction linked to the category.
It seems easy but I can't get it to work due to the following problem:
My database model is the following:

```
//Transaction
TransactionID
Quantity
CategoryID
UserID
//Category
ID
Name
//User
ID
Name
```

The problem is returning a json/xml response with for example:

```
User1
--Cate1
----Tran1
----Tran2
--Cate2
----Tran3
User2
--Cate1
----Tran4
```

Because there is no separate link between User and Category only with transaction and I don't know how I can fix this with LINQ queries or something else.

--Edit
My Controller code:

```
        List<User> Users = new List<User> {
        new User {Id = 1, Name = "Matt" },
        new User {Id = 2, Name = "Bill" },
        new User {Id = 3, Name = "Peter" },
        new User {Id = 4, Name = "Bart" }
    };
    List<Category> Categories = new List<Category> {
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Sales" },
        new Category {Id = 2, Name = "After Sales" },
        new Category {Id = 3, Name = "Pre Sales" }
    };
    List<Transaction> Transactions = new List<Transaction> {
        new Transaction {Id = 1, Quantity = 200, CategoryId = 1 , UserId = 1},
        new Transaction {Id = 2, Quantity = 150, CategoryId = 2 , UserId = 1 },
        new Transaction {Id = 3, Quantity = 300, CategoryId = 2 , UserId = 1 },
        new Transaction {Id = 4, Quantity = 100, CategoryId = 1 , UserId = 2},
        new Transaction {Id = 5, Quantity = 150, CategoryId = 2 , UserId = 2 },
        new Transaction {Id = 6, Quantity = 250, CategoryId = 3 , UserId = 3 },
        new Transaction {Id = 7, Quantity = 200, CategoryId = 1 , UserId = 4},
        new Transaction {Id = 8, Quantity = 50, CategoryId = 2 , UserId = 4 },
        new Transaction {Id = 9, Quantity = 250, CategoryId = 3 , UserId = 4 }
    };
    //(new int[] { 2, 3, 5 });

    public List<UserDTO> Get()
    {
        var User = from d in Users
                   select new UserDTO
                   {
                       User = d,
                       /* Here I have the Problem
                        * I can't link the categories to the users without calling all transactions
                        * And then the result will for UserId = 1 will return 3 categories but 2 times After Sales and I want to return it onces
                       */
                       Categories = (from c in Transactions
                                     where c.UserId == d.Id
                                     select new CategoryDTO
                                     {
                                         Category = c.Category,
                                         Transactions = (from t in Transactions
                                                         where t.CategoryId == c.CategoryId && t.UserId == c.UserId
                                                         select new TransactionDTO
                                                         {
                                                             Id = t.Id,
                                                             Quantity = t.Quantity
                                                         }).ToList()
                                     }).ToList()

                   };
        return User.ToList();
    }
```

All the DTO classes:

```
    public class UserDTO
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryDTO> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionDTO> Transactions { get; set; }
}
public class TransactionDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, you say you want to output the data as `User -> Category -> Transaction` and then complain that this is the type of output you get...

Comment: No the example at the end is the result I want. Just a more in detail

Comment: but you already have the relationship there, show us what you are currently doing and why it doesn't give you the desired output.

Comment: start by getting a queryable over transactions, group by user then by categories. return a new user at high level and new category at middle level. last level return your transaction. you'll need to create own DTO classes to do it

Comment: It sounds like your data structure actually categorizes Transactions rather than Users.  Do users belong to Categories, or do Transactions?  My suggestion is to first build a SQL query to see if you can get your desired results, then translate into Linq.

Comment: The sql query is simple only returning it in the correct layout is not easy from me, query -> Select * from transactions t inner join users u on t.UserId = u.id inner join categories c on t.CategoryId = c.Id

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to group by `Category` in order to produce the output you want:

```
var User = from d in Users
           select new UserDTO
           {
               User = d,
               Categories = (from t in Transactions
                             where t.UserId == d.Id
                             group t by t.Category into g   // <-- group by category
                             select new CategoryDTO
                             {
                                 Category = g.Key,
                                 Transactions = from ct in g
                                                 select new TransactionDTO
                                                 {
                                                     Id = ct.Id,
                                                     Quantity = ct.Quantity
                                                 }).ToList()
                             }).ToList()

           };
return User.ToList();
```

Note that if your object model had navigation properties it would be a *little* simpler:

```
var User = from d in Users
           select new UserDTO
           {
               User = d,
               Categories = (from t in d.Transactions
                             group t by t.Category into g   // <-- group by category
                             select new CategoryDTO
                             {
                                 Category = g.Key,
                                 Transactions = from ct in g
                                                 select new TransactionDTO
                                                 {
                                                     Id = ct.Id,
                                                     Quantity = ct.Quantity
                                                 }).ToList()
                             }).ToList()

           };
return User.ToList();
```

Another option would be to use a sub-model to group transactions into categories - that might reduce some of the confusion of having users linked directly to categories (when they really belong to transactions).